# triggering radio button onChange or onSelect in antd table on row click?

Tags: antd

I'm trying to select antd table row onClick...
I managed to set the "selectedRowKeys" on the click of the row...and the row is getting selected

```
<Table onRow={(record: any, rowIndex: number) => ({
      onClick: () => {
        setSelectedKeys([record.key]);
      },}...
```

the problem is that the onChange and onSelect for the "rowSelection" object are not firing on row click (only on direct radio button select) ...am I doing something wrong?!

```
 const rowSelection = {
selectedRowKeys: selectedKeys,
onSelect: (record: T, selected: boolean) => {console.log("on select");},
onChange:.....
```

sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/row-selection-events-not-firing-in-antd-table-zus9x

Comment: Add a jsfiddle or plnkr link where we can edit and test. Will be more helpful for you too.

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal sorry for yesterday...I noticed that I didn't save my sandbox modifications...so it was a template code...first timer :( ... it is working now

Answer (score 0):

I just added console.logs in onRow>onClick and if I use this code:

```
console.log(selectedKeys);
  return (
    <Table
      rowSelection={{
        type: "radio",
        ...myRowSelection
      }}
      columns={myColumns}
      dataSource={data}
      onRow={(record, rowIndex) => ({
        onClick: () => {
          console.log("Row onclick");
          console.log(record);
          setSelectedKeys([record.key]);
        }
      })}
    />
  );
```

Then it seems like your row onclick is being called and it's setting the correct selected keys. It's also selecting the correct row.

The below code only refers to the radio button so it's only impacted by the radio button onSelect and onChange

```
const myRowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys: selectedKeys,
    onSelect: (record, selected) => {
      console.log(record);
    },
    onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
      console.log(
        `selectedRowKeys: ${selectedRowKeys}`,
        "selectedRows: ",
        selectedRows
      );
    }
  };
```

See here is where you link that code to the radio button

```
rowSelection={{
        type: "radio",
        ...myRowSelection
      }}
```

If you want to trigger the onChange by selecting a row, I recommend you call an onChange() function inside onRow onClick like so:

```
onRow={(record, rowIndex) => ({
        onClick: () => {
             //CALL THE ONCHANGE FUNCTION HERE AND IT WILL BE TRIGGERED ON ROW SELECTION
             onChange([record.key]);
             //and then do whatever you want in the onChange function
        }
      })}
```

Comment: what I really need is for the radio button to get 'focus'...so the table responds to keyboard navigation through arrow up and down...and if the radio is getting selected ... shouldn't "onSelect" be triggered?!! Is  this considered a bug or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
 const myRowSelection = {
 selectedRowKeys: selectedKeys,

  onSelect: (record) => {
    console.log('selected', record);
    setSelectedKeys([record.key]);
  },
  selectedRowKeys: selectedKeys,  };


 <Table
  rowSelection={{
    type: "radio",
    ...myRowSelection
  }}
  columns={myColumns}
  dataSource={data}
  onRow={(record) => ({
    onClick: () => {
      console.log('click', record);
      setSelectedKeys([record.key]);
    }
  })}
/>
```

it's work for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is intended behavior as this issue states:
[antd issue 30538](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/30538)